# Vim key binding that mimic emacs CTL-K

Tags: vim, emacs, editor

I'm trying to create a vim key-binding that mimic emacs CTL-K:

> 1. If used at the end of a line, it kills the line-ending newline character, merging the next line into the current one (thus, a blank line is entirely removed).
> 2. Otherwise, C-k kills all the text from point up to the end of the line;
> 3. if point was originally at the beginning of the line, this leaves the line blank.

I saw an answer at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/301584/137686 recommending the following

```
inoremap <C-K> <Esc>lDa
```

It seems to work for case 2, but not for case 1 (it won't delete the newline character) or 3 (it will leave the first character in the line). Any recommendation on how I can improve the mapping to achieve all three?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Give this `expr` mapping a try:

```
inoremap <expr> <c-k> '<c-o>'.(col('.')==col('$')?'J':'D')
```

It checks your current cursor position, to decide to do a `D` or `J`.

`c-o` makes sure that return to the insert mode after the operation.

#### Note

insert mode `ctrl-k` is very useful to enter digraphs. Think twice if you want to disable the function with your mapping.

Comment: What kind of sorcery is this?

Comment: @Meitham `:h map-expr`

Answer (score 4):

I wrote a function to achieve this:

```
inoremap <C-K> <c-r>=CtrlK()<cr>

function! CtrlK()
    let col = col('.')
    let end = col('$')

    if col == end
        return "\<Del>"
    elseif col == 1
        return "\<Esc>cc"
    else
        return "\<Esc>lc$"
    endif
endfunction
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need a one-line mapping to play around, you can use this:

`inoremap <C-K> <Esc>:if col(".")==col("$")-1\|exe "normal gJh"\|else\|exe "normal lD"\|endif<Enter>a`

I haven't tested for edge cases, but I'm sure this will be enough to get you started.